# (Mix) Hex dependency resolution failed

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I'm new to phoenix and elixir... I'm trying to get the dependencies and when I run the following command, I get the error. Am I missing something? Still trying to figure it out what the actual error means?

`mix deps.get ueberauth_auth0`

```
Resolving Hex dependencies...
#Incompatibility<#Term, cause: {:conflict, #Incompatibility<#Term<ueberauth_auth0 >= 0.4.0>, cause: {:conflict, #Incompatibility<#Term<ueberauth_auth0 >= 0.4.0>, #Term<not oauth2 ~> 2.0>, cause: :dependency>, #Incompatibility<#Term, #Term<not oauth2 ~> 0.5>, cause: :dependency>}>, #Incompatibility<#Term, #Term<not ueberauth_auth0 ~> 2.1.0>, cause: :dependency>}> Resolution completed in 0.822s Because ueberauth_auth0 >= 0.4.0 depends on oauth2 ~> 2.0 and your app depends on oauth2 ~> 0.5, ueberauth_auth0 >= 0.4.0 is forbidden. So, because your app depends on ueberauth_auth0 ~> 2.1.0, version solving failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have override the plugin and the error disappeared.

```
{:ueberauth_auth0, "~> 2.1.0", override: true}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to bump the version of the library to the patch (`~> 0.4.0`) in your `mix.exs` file, which effectively allows `0.4.0 ≤ version < 0.5.0` and `ueberauth` itself to `2.0` or like.

Make it less restrictive: start with `mix hex.info ueberauth_auth0`, figure out what is the best suited version to eliminate a conflict and bump it in your `mix.exs` to that value.